# How to customize FullCalendar year view

Tags: events, calendar, fullcalendar

I am using Full Calendar for event management utility in one of my project. However, my requirement is to show a year view similar to one shown here (as I want to display event in a similar fashion. Ignore the red dot).

I tried forking the original code to make some changes, but could make much out of it. Seems like every view gets a lot from common code, not much distinction among different views.

[image]

Is there a way to achieve this using FullCalendar. Or is there any other known library to achieve this. Our project is looking for a supported library only